# 2.78 - switching between current shading mode and rendered one not work

Tags: 3d-view

Switching between current shading mode and rendered one in new blender 2,78 not work for me after I imported my custom keyconfiguration. After resetting to factory settings it works. Can I manually turn this feature somewhere or it is bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been some recent changes in the default keymap for 2.78, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> now toggles between the current mode and *Rendered* mode, as opposed to before where it toggled always between *SOLID* and *Rendered* according to the [release notes in the wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.78/Viewport).

Unfortunately Blender key map editor is not that good with merging changes between custom keymaps and changes to the official one.

My advice advice to you is to check out the new default keymap and manually copy the relevant operators like `view3d.toggle_render` and their corresponding key maps from there and paste it into your own custom key map with whatever new key binding you want, making sure you delete the old ones and eliminate any conflicts.